# Using Iterable Protocol for JavaScript generator function does not reach return statement

Tags: javascript, iterator, generator, iterable

I'm trying to learn about generator functions in javascript and am experimenting with using a `for..of` loop in order to iterate over my yield statements. One thing I noticed is that the function terminates after the final yield statement and does not attempt to execute the return statement. If I were to create a generator object and call generator.next() 4 times, the return statement would trigger and we would see the associated generator object. Would anyone have any idea what's going on under the hood to cause this behavior?

Thanks!

```
function* generator(){

    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3

    return "hello there"
}


for (const value of generator()){
    console.log('value', value)
}
```

Comment: check the `done` inforamation, read the doc!

Answer (score 1):

> the function terminates after the final yield statement and does not attempt to execute the return statement

This is wrong, the `return` statement *is* executed, which is easy to see with

```js
function* generator() {
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
    console.log('returning')
    return "hello there"
}

for (const value of generator()) {
    console.log('value', value)
}
```

And indeed the `next` method is called 4 times by the loop:

```js
function* generator() {
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
    return "hello there"
}
const iterator = {
    state: generator(),
    [Symbol.iterator]() { return this; },
    next(...args) {
        const res = this.state.next(...args)
        console.log(res)
        return res
    },
}
for (const value of iterator) {
    console.log('value', value)
}
```

However, the return value, not being a yielded value, marks the end of the iteration and does not get to become a `value` in the `for` loop body, which only runs 3 times. If you wanted it to run 4 times, you'd need to `yield` 4 values.